# Microsoft deprecated cross-signing certificates, what's the new procedure to sign kernel drivers for Windows 11 & 10?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver-signing

[Microsoft deprecated cross-signing certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/deprecation-of-software-publisher-certificates-and-commercial-release-certificates), however, it's not clear from the docs what's the new procedure.

From the docs above MS is the sole provider but their support claims you can still get one from other vendors (e.g. Digicert, Globalsign, etc...)

Does anybody know what's the process for signing production kernel drivers for Windows 11 & 10?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself, but if you want to make a kernel module for Windows 10 or 11 I think you're supposed to use "attestation signing".  The page you linked to has a link named "attestation signing" that goes here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/attestation-signing-a-kernel-driver-for-public-release

Basically you make a driver, sign it with an EV certificate from a certificate authority, and then you submit to be checked and signed by Microsoft using a website called the "Hardware Developer Center Dashboard portal".  I have also seen Microsoft use some other names for the website:  "Hardware Dev Center Dashboard" and "Partner Center".

You don't need to use the portal if you are making a simple INF-only driver, or you are using a kernal module that is part of Windows, or you are using a kernel module that was already signed properly by another party.

Here is the original announcement from 2015 introducing the portal:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-hardware-certification/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10/ba-p/364859

There's more info in this long article I wrote: https://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of attestation signing and used it in the past, however, since that document hasn't been updated since 2017 and MS changed the process afterwards, how can I be certain it will still work?
you also wrote "... and signed by MS", did you refer to cross-signing (the deprecated procedure) or something else? and if the latter, what exactly?
appreciated!

Comment: My understanding is that Microsoft applies an appropriate signature to your driver after you submit it to them, and their signature will be good enough to get it loaded on whatever operating systems you requested when using the portal.  It would be different from the old cross signing thing but I don't think we need to know the details since Microsoft would take care of making the signature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we followed the suggestion (this is similar what Microsoft also suggested) and it took us a while to receive the certificate, however it didn't work and now the driver doesn't load with error 0x800B010C "A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer." despite all the certificates being valid as tested by running "signtool verify /v /va /all <file>".
Any ideas?

Comment: What certificate are you talking about and who gave it to you?  Have you double clicked on it and inspected it and its whole chain of trust?  Sounds like the issuer has an error on their end.  Most certificates come with a URL for a certificate revocation list which is basically a website where the issuer can revoke certificates in case something goes wrong (like the certificate was abused or its private key was leaked).  I am not sure if signtool checks certificate revocation lists or not.

Comment: Thanks @David, it's an **EV** certificate from Certum and we already checked the whole chain and verified the CRL manually, our certificate is not revoked, and the CRL for MS' hardware (used in attestation signing) is empty.